# Visual Studio 2019 Net 5 ASP.NET Core WebApp Error MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I create a project as per the screenshots and the following error appears when I try to Build or Run.

[image]
[image]
[image]
Error   MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks  WebApplication1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    1177

[image]

Below is my about screen, shouldn't show with Net Version 5.0 as opposed to Version 4.8.03752?

If I visit the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers

It states that my NET version was part of my Visual Studio 2019 (16.3 update)

Comment: .NET 5 is supported in the latest VS version, 16.8. You need to upgrade your Visual Studio version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 5 is actually .NET Core 5 and replaces .NET 4.x. New development continues on the .NET Core line only. .NET Old will only get fixes from now on. That's why you won't see any .NET Old versions beyond 4.8 in Visual Studio.

.NET 5 is supported in the latest Visual Studio version, 16.8. You need to upgrade to the latest version. The final of both .NET 5 and Visual Studio 16.8 were released yesterday during [dotNETConf 2020](https://www.dotnetconf.net/). You can find the [first day's sessions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mS6ykjdOVRg) in [.NET's YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvtT19MZW8dq5Wwfu6B0oxw).

The sessions explain what .NET 5 is, what's new, how to port existing applications from .NET Framework 4.x to .NET 5 including desktop applications like Windows Forms and WPF applications.

Some early .NET 5 previews were supported in 16.7 but the latest previews and RC versions were only supported on 16.8

Comment: I am not converting my project just yet. I am doing simple WebApplications just to  review and then upgrade my projects. I just upgraded my version to Visual Studio 16.8 and this has solved this error. And yes, the dotNETConf2020 is great to watch.